# UPDATE a data in SPARQL query

Tags: sparql, rdf, insert-update

I would like to ask you for help with my SPARQL query. I am trying to update one piece of data from a RDF file.

Example from RDF file:

```
<xd:Book rdf:ID="_12abcd34">
<xd:Object.description>123</xd:Object.description>
<xd:Object.name>ABC</xd:Object.name>
</xd:Book>
```

I need to update description from "123" to "456" in all books with Object.name ABC for example. I was trying something like this:

```
DELETE { ?Book xd:Object.description ?desc . } 
INSERT { ?Book xd:Object.description "456" .}
WHERE  { ?Book xd:Object.name "ABC" .};
```

I have no error but the query is not working. Please let me know if you need any additional explanation. Thank you for your help!

Eduard

Comment: What you've shown looks OK. Are you certain the prefix definition for xd is identical in your data and the SPARQL?

Comment: Prefixes looks fine. The code runs but the output file is empty. There is no need to SELECT/CONSTRUCT in a query? 
I need to copy INPUT data to the empty OUTPUT data file just with adapted description. Thanks for reply.

Comment: Which API, which triple store?

Comment: And for SPARQL, it's always good to have a look at the data in Turtle format as SPARQL triple patterns itself use the same notation.

Comment: Yes, the query looks fine.  How do you know it doesn't work?  Without seeing the full query (with prefixes, etc.) And data with prefixes, it's hard to say.  But what does a simple select query with that same where body return? Is it actually finding the individuals that you'd expect?

Comment: You were right. The problem was because of wrongly defined prefixes. I am sorry to waste your time. Thank you all for help!!!